# Untangle Internet Blocking

Tags: internet, blocking, untangle

In Untangle I need to block users' Internet whose MAC are not added in DHCP. If I enable DHCP, it should not fetch any IP automatically. Only Internet should go to the PCs whose MAC addresses have been listed in the Server.

How can I set this up in Untangle?

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: Many routers have this function built in, usually it is called something like MAC filtering.

Answer (score 0):

David Actually We are using Untangle server in that if i enable DHCP in server it assigns IPs automatically to the users PC. I need to block internet for the people whose MAC id are not added in the Server.Simple term if i say Internet should work only for the people whose mac addrsss was added in server.Not Static or Not auotmatic IP.